# D3 x-axis format based on zoom level

Tags: javascript, d3.js, format, zooming

TLDR: I want to make changes to my format at different zoom levels. Right now, I'm just trying to copy the default formatting.

By default (I assume, I'm working with existing code), my timeline's x-axis start at years and becomes more granular on zoom-in until it reaches hours. When I apply custom multi-scale formatting, I lose the everything except a single format

I've seen several examples of multi-scale tick formats and thought that was the way to go. However, my time always has a year, month, day, and hour value so the multi-scale tickFormats that I've seen/tried always show hour values. The default tickFormat doesn't seem to have this issue.

Here's the tickFormat function that I've been testing in an attempt to mimic the default before making my adjustments:

```
const multiFormat = (date: Date) => {
  const formatMillisecond = d3.timeFormat('.%L'),
    formatSecond = d3.timeFormat(':%S'),
    formatMinute = d3.timeFormat('%I:%M'),
    formatHour = d3.timeFormat('%I %p'),
    formatDay = d3.timeFormat('%a %d'),
    formatWeek = d3.timeFormat('%b %d'),
    formatMonth = d3.timeFormat('%B'),
    formatYear = d3.timeFormat('%Y')

  return (d3.timeSecond(date) < date
    ? formatMillisecond
    : d3.timeMinute(date) < date
    ? formatSecond
    : d3.timeHour(date) < date
    ? formatMinute
    : d3.timeDay(date) < date
    ? formatHour
    : d3.timeMonth(date) < date
    ? d3.timeWeek(date) < date
      ? formatDay
      : formatWeek
    : d3.timeYear(date) < date
    ? formatMonth
    : formatYear)(date)
}
```

Visual examples:

Here is part of the timeline with the default x-axis (zoomed out/in)

[image: Default tickFormat zoomed out]
[image: Default tickFormat zoomed in]

Here is with my tickFormat (zoomed out/in)

[image: My tickFormat zoomed out]
[image: My tickFormat zoomed in]

Answer (score 0):

So, the missing piece of the puzzle seems to be the d3.utc[time_frame] functions (e.g. d3.utcSecond). This seems to solve the issue and give us a the default tickFormat.

This is what I ended up with (could probably use some refactoring for clarity):

```
function multiFormat(date: Date) {
  return (d3.utcSecond(date) < date
    ? d3.timeFormat('.%L')
    : d3.utcMinute(date) < date
    ? d3.timeFormat(':%S')
    : d3.utcHour(date) < date
    ? d3.timeFormat('%H:%M')
    : d3.utcDay(date) < date
    ? d3.timeFormat('%H %p')
    : d3.utcMonth(date) < date
    ? d3.utcWeek(date) < date
      ? d3.timeFormat('%a %d')
      : d3.timeFormat('%b %d')
    : d3.utcYear(date) < date
    ? d3.timeFormat('%B')
    : d3.timeFormat('%Y'))(date)
}
```